# Different characterizations of Liouville numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, continued-fractions

Usually, Liouville numbers are defined as follows:
$x$ is Liouville if for ever $i\in\mathbb N$ there exist $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left|x-\frac nm\right|<\frac1{m^i}.
\end{equation}
In their paper on almost-periodic Schrödinger operators, however, Avron and Simon use the following definition:
$x$ is Liouville if for ever $i\in\mathbb N$ there exist $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left|x-\frac nm\right|<\frac1{i^m}.
\end{equation}
Can one show that these sets of numbers agree?

Comment: They definitely don't agree. The "original" Liouville number $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k!}$ satisfies the first definition but not the second definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...yet both sets are of measure 0 and dense Gδ...and surely the second set is contained in the first...but why do Avron and Simon coin them Liouville numbers, then? Only a misuse of terminology?

Comment: Without being provided even a link to the paper, we can't even speculate.

Comment: Indeed, my bad...this one:
http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/149.pdf
The definition of Liouville numbers appears on p.5 and the result is Corollary 7.2.
As far as I understand this definition is needed to prove Gordon's Theorem.